# Search View close icon not visible when expanded

Tags: android, searchview, android-toolbar

I have a searchView added on a toolBar. Collapsed state looks like this.

[image: Collapsed Search View]

Expanded state looks like this.

[image]

Why is the searchView close icon not displayed?

**toolbar.xml**

```
android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
```

**menu.xml**

```
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
   </menu>
```

Comment: That is how the `SearchView` is intended to look in its expanded state. I was confused at first too because I was expecting an "X" to be visible to close the `SearchView`. That is not the case. The back arrow will close the SearchView and the soft keyboard if it is open.

Answer (score 2):

Okay. I figured something out. But not exactly nice looking as above. Did the following changes.

In activity class

```
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
```

and in menu,

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

Then it looks like this, but not a very nice view since the navigation drawer is visible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Only `ifRoom` worked for me.

```
   <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="@string/menu_search_video"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

Thanks.